# Objeto javascript não cria novas keys

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Estou usando MongoDB e me retorna todos os dados certo mas quando eu quero adicionar uma nova Key simplesmente não cria.

```
exports.validaLogin = function(req, res) {
login.find({
  "nome": req.query.usuario
},function (err, logins) {
  if(err) { 
    return handleError(res, err);
  }
  var usuario = logins[0]
  if(usuario.senha == req.query.senha){
    usuario.status = 1
    console.log("aqui")
  } else {
    console.log("nao")
    usuario.status = 0
  }
  console.log(usuario)
  return res.status(200).json(usuario);
}); };
```

No meu console.log apos a validação o resultado é este, tanto no se como no senão.

```
{ _id: 59fa1a69349c9f382f0a2892,
   nome: 'qqqqqqq',
   telefone: '189789469',
   curso: 'eeeeee',
   email: 'teste',
   senha: 2651
   codigo: 2,
__v: 0 }
```

Comment: E onde está o código para criação? Pode posta-lo?

Comment: Você esta se referindo ao código de criação do banco ?

Comment: Exato, o código que gera o erro (falha na criação da key), a não ser que entendi mal sua pergunta

Comment: Não mostra nenhum código de erro, eu tento atribuir a key status e no console.log que recebo a key status não existe.

Comment: Se fizeres `var usuario = Object.merge({}, logins[0]);` já funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mongo usa um getter para os dados.
Se tu quiser alterar o valor (ou adicionar novos dados), deve ser usado o `usuario._doc`.

`let usuarioCopy = usuario._doc;
usuarioCopy.status = 0;
console.log(usuarioCopy);`

*Obs: Nesse meu exemplo, usuarioCopy não é realmente uma cópia. alterar ele altera os dados de usuario._doc.*

Comment: A bom agora entendi melhor como o mongo me retorna os dados, estou iniciando com mongo e não entendo bem ainda, obrigado